# Image not aligning to the right on gmail,outlook and yahoo mail

Tags: html-email, email-client, email-templates

I'm new to email template designs and I'm wondering why this is happening to my email template. The first screen shot is what I expect and the others are what is rendered in gmail, yahoo and outlook respectively. My concern is why is the logo not being aligned to the right as expected. I've also attached the corresponding code that shows the logo.

[image: Expected][image][image][image]

```html
<tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top">
 <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
 <!--
 The centering table keeps the content
 tables centered in the emailBody table,
 in case its width is set to 100%.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top">
 <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
 <!--
 The flexible container has a set width
 that gets overridden by the media query.
 Most content tables within can then be
 given 100% widths.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" class="flexibleContainerCell">

 <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
 <!--
 The content table is the first element
 that's entirely separate from the structural
 framework of the email.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top" class="textContent">
 <img align="right" alt="accesbank-logo" src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/euel9v.jpg" /><br /><br />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of align center on the td's which need to be align right as the logo is in a table that is supposed to be aligned right.

I have added an extra table and made it the same size as the logo and aligned it right.

```html
 <tr>
 <td align="right" valign="top">
 <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
 <!--
 The centering table keeps the content
 tables centered in the emailBody table,
 in case its width is set to 100%.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
 <tr>
 <td align="right" valign="top">
 <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
 <!--
 The flexible container has a set width
 that gets overridden by the media query.
 Most content tables within can then be
 given 100% widths.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer">
 <tr>
 <td align="right" valign="top" width="600" class="flexibleContainerCell">

 <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
 <!--
 The content table is the first element
 that's entirely separate from the structural
 framework of the email.
 -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td align="right" valign="top" class="textContent">

 <table width="152" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; max-width: 152px;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td align="right"><img alt="accesbank-logo" src="http://oi65.tinypic.com/euel9v.jpg" /></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Let me know if this fixes it. If this doesn't fix the issue then we will need more code to see if there is any conflicting class or ID that is causing teh template to go eider than the design.

Is this part of a hybrid or responsive email?

Cheers

Comment: Thank you Syfer, unfortunately, the code is longer than what is acceptable on stack-overflow. Please if you provide me with your email, I will send you the full html source in a zip file.

Comment: Syfer.darknight at gmail

Comment: As discussed the offending code was two vertical align that was causing issues in Dreamweaver. Once that was fixed i placed you header block with the body of the code so the alignments were perfect.